# Unknown Ψ variable in JFET's drain current equation

Tags: capacitance, fet, conductivity, formula-derivation

This question considers unipolar transistor, that is JFET.

I really didn't find any other formula than this one which applies only for linear/ohmic/triode region of JFET U/I characteristic.

What is the variables marked as "Ψ" (psi) in the next equation (underlined with green colour)?
[image]

The unknown variable can be also seen here:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, if you rearrange the following formula you should get your formula: -

[image]

The [web page](https://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/current/postgraduate/regs/mpags/ex5/devices/mesfet/) that shows this formula state that: -

> Vi is the Schottky diode potential barrier

Vi appears to be the psi constant in your equation.

Comment: Has Vi its own formula definition too or is there just a constant value for it?

Comment: I think you might need to research that. I'm not that hot on semi conductor physics but I did somewhat recognize the formula and knew where to look.

Comment: Ahh yes, MESFET works on principle that includes the schottky barrier effect, but that applies just for MESFET!

Comment: @Keno given the similarity of the placement of the psi variable in the equation I think you should be looking for something that is equivalent to psi but for the JFET.

Comment: Yes, true. But still can't find equivalent variable to psi because I still don't know what psi represents here.

Comment: The formula in your question.... Can you link the web page?

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/0471200689.app6/pdf

Comment: Here's another one that uses it: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjImKaPlfLSAhWBD8AKHfvtAwUQFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmgh-courses.ece.gatech.edu%2Fece4430%2FECE4430%2FUnit1%2FLectureNotes%2FJFET01.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG5bcJjoVVGBU8AeghRKCQV2ONEnw&sig2=Slvk5VF57vm92s_Rx3bmuA&cad=rja

Comment: Aha it's in here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=29&ved=0ahUKEwi_jp2slvLSAhXDDsAKHZ_zB9o4FBAWCEcwCA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandiego.edu%2F~ekim%2Fe194rfs01%2Ffetfreq.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGZNFxI-ZLUrTxs8nJ7SlyC5JBZxw&sig2=yQ1SKCx2C6lDTV9WanUv8w&cad=rja it's the gate junction (barrier) potential!!!

Comment: And this one: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiwg5rwlvLSAhVsLsAKHYnSASgQFggmMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmgh-courses.ece.gatech.edu%2Fece4430%2FECE4430%2FUnit1%2FLectureNotes%2Fday01.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHroJL5Zlkbsb4XirDEcUY-g2P91A&sig2=AyejEK-fxteORbMqMwXRNg&cad=rja

Comment: Nice.. Where do you find all the stuff like this?

Comment: Since you have been struggling with this question all the way here, I want to ask you if the channel length modulation parameter (a.k.a. lambda - http://mgh-courses.ece.gatech.edu/ece4430/ECE4430/Unit1/LectureNotes/JFET01.pdf - page 9) can be valued as it says here (0,01) since no datasheet provides that kind of information?

Comment: Semiconductor physics is not my strong point.

Comment: I managed to search on google using the psi symbol and just looked at a few pdfs